# Creating 0.000.. with certain decimals

Tags: java, double, digits

I am trying to create the number 0.00000.... with as many '0' as the user input wants. What is wrong with my code below?

```
      int n;
      double dec = 0.0;

   in = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = in.nextInt();

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
                dec = dec / 10.0d;
```

Number doesn't change.

Comment: 0.000000000 = 0. What are you trying to accomplish? A particular display, or what?

Comment: You keep dividing 0 by 10.0 (dec = 0.0) - which remains 0.

Comment: if you want to display 0.0000000, then try it using String, not double.

Comment: I'm interested in obtaining 0.0000. I will convert it to string later on and use it   String toString;
        toString = Double.toString(dec);
        DecimalFormat decFor = new DecimalFormat(toString);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're expecting `double` to retain the number of decimal digits - it doesn't do that. The value is always normalized. The `double` type is all about the magnitude of a number, not a particular decimal representation. It's suitable for naturally occurring quantities - weights, heights etc.

If you care about decimal digits, then [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is a more suitable type for you. This is more appropriate for currency values for example, where there really is a precise amount specified as a decimal representation.

`BigDecimal` *does* retain the number of decimal digits you use, but you'll need to be careful about *exactly* how you use it. You'll no doubt find the [`setScale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int%29) method useful.

For example:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("0")
        System.out.println(x); // 0
        x = x.setScale(5);
        System.out.println(x); // 0.00000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to display the decimal point according to user input,  Try

```
int n;
double dec = 0.0;

in = new Scanner(System.in);
n = in.nextInt(); //number of decimal places

System.out.println(String.format("%."+n+"f",dec));
```

Answer (score 0):

`0.0`, `0.00`, `0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` and so on are exactly the same value; Java literally can't tell them apart during runtime. No matter how many times you divide it by `10`, it will remain EXACTLY the same number.

When being printed, trailing zero digits are omitted (unless explicitly specified in, for instance, `String.format`).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you are trying to do is keep on dividing `0.0`. But it'll always give you the same result as Java considers `0.000` as `0.0`. Even `0.0000000000000000` will be considered as `0.0`. If you just want to display that many `0`s, then save it in a `String` and then display.

```
...
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("0.");
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    s.append("0");
String num = s.toString();
//Then use it.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need string with user defined '0':

```
public static String FormatZero( int accurancy_ ) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    if( 0 >= accurancy_ )
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "accurancy_must be > 0" );

    }

    String  formatString    = "0.";

    for( int i = 0 ; i < accurancy_ ; ++i )
    {
        formatString    += "0";

    }

    DecimalFormat   format  = new DecimalFormat( formatString );
    String      result  = format.format( 0d );

    return result;

}
```